# How to be sure that object with events can be collected?

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, telerik, mvvm-light

I have VirtualDataCollection with event

```
VirtualDataCollection.ItemsLoading += VirtualDataCollectionOnItemsLoading;
```

I cant unsubscribe inside of event, because it can be called random amount of times. How to be sure, that instance would be collected by GC? I read some articles about leaking with unsubscribed events( like [this](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/02/01/memory-profiling-for-application-performance.aspx)). Also, afaik, it is wrong to set

```
VirtualDataCollection.ItemsLoading = null;
```

For now, i'm using

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom()
    {
        VirtualDataCollection.Clear();
        VirtualDataCollection = null;
        Cleanup();
    }
```

But is that enoguh?

EDIT: hm.. actually, i can also add

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom()
    {
        VirtualDataCollection.ItemsLoading -= VirtualDataCollectionOnItemsLoading;
        VirtualDataCollection.Clear();
        VirtualDataCollection = null;
        Cleanup();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to be sure, that instance would be collected by GC?

If you're only worried about the GC side of things and it failing to collect the *publishing* instance, don't be. There are references from the event publisher to the event handlers, but not the other way round.

Comment: So, if i'm setting event publisher (VirtualDataCollection) to null, it would be not referenced from event handler (VirtualDataCollectionOnItemsLoading), and it would be cleaned by the GC?